Why initial segment of ordinals(Theorem 2.27 Thomas Jech)
Small detail in Theorem 2.27 of Set theory by Thomas Jech(everything understood except this small detail). Let $P$ be well-founded. There exists a unique $\rho: P \rightarrow Ord$ such that
$$\rho(x) = sup\{\rho(y) + 1 : yEx\}$$
How is the range of $\rho$ an initial segment of $Ord$? I see no reason. How
$$\alpha \in \rho(x)$$
leads to $\alpha = \rho(y)$ for some $y$? [Please don't ignore this question :-)]

Is this "Set Theory" or "The Axiom of Choice" by Jech?

It's set theory :-)

My copy starts Thm. 2.27 as "If $E$ is a well-founded relation on $P$, then there exists..."

So? I don't get you.

Where does $\rho$ send $x$ if there is no $y$ such that $y\ E\ x$?  (That is, where does $\rho$ send the $E$-minimal element of $P$?)

You have "Let $P$ be well-founded..."  Well-foundedness is a property of relations, not of sets.

@EricTowers An $E$-minimal element of $P$ is sent to $\sup\varnothing=0$.

@EricTowers That's really nitpicky. Do you also complain about "Let $G$ be a group..." when $G$ is just the domain of a group?

@AndreasBlass : Really targeted for the OP...  So let $x_0$ be the $E$-minimal element of $P$, and we know $\rho(x_0) = 0$.  Now let $x_1$ be the $E$-minimal element of $P \smallsetminus {x_0}$.  Could it be that $\rho(x_1)$ must be $1$?  Can you see how this gives an initial segment of the ordinals and cannot have gaps?

@JonathanSchilhan : When first introducing a concept, ensuring that it is associated with the correct category is a very good idea.

Suppose, toward a contradiction, that the claim is false. Among all possible pairs $(\alpha,x)$ with $\alpha<\rho(x)$ but $\alpha\notin\text{Range}(\rho)$, consider one for which $\rho(x)$ is as small as possible. Since $\alpha<\rho(x)$, the definition of $\rho$ tells us that there is some $y$ with $yEx$ and $\alpha<\rho(y)+1$. That means $\alpha\leq\rho(y)$, but since
$\alpha\notin\text{Range}(\rho)$ we actually get $\alpha<\rho(y).$ Then $(\alpha,y)$ is among the pairs considered above, so minimality of $\rho(x)$ tells us that $\rho(x)\leq\rho(y)$. That is absurd, since $yEx$.
